# How do I calculate the interior area of four bounding circles?

Tags: integration, area

My integral calculus is rusty.
How do I calculate the interior area (blue region) of four bounding circles?
[image]

Comment: let radius = 1, then 4- pi/4

Comment: @ZackNi should be 4-pi = area of square - area of circle

Comment: @GCab my logical error

Comment: wow. why did someone vote this question down. clearly, a well defined (albeit radius not specified) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need integrals for that. You can quickly show that the blue area in your picture is the same as the blue area in the picture below: [image]

Comment: so its 1 - pi / 4 if the radius of circle is 1/2 ?
Your example blue is (1- pi/4).
Mine is: a quarter of your area, times by 4 repetitions. so its the same right?

Comment: @jsky Yes. Or you can cut your blue area in 4 and put it around one circle.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Draw a square around your circles. Then you do not need any integrals, only the area of the circles (and of the square).

Comment: thanks. yours is the same answer as 5xum, but he spelt it out for me

Answer (score 1):

Let radius of circle is $a$,then "area is=area of square -area of a cirle"
$$S={ 4a }^{ 2 }-\pi { a }^{ 2 }={ a }^{ 2 }\left( 4-\pi  \right) $$
[image]

Comment: oh i see what you did now. thanks. the other answer got me there faster.

Comment: actually. it should be (2a)^2 - pi * a^2

Comment: @jsky,thanks ,it was typo

Answer (score 1):

Consider the square joining the centres of the circles:

[image]

Comment: thanks yours is same as Battani. the other approach clicked first.

Comment: Fair enough! Glad you understand the problem